# How to refresh a page inside another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have 2 pages and in the first page, I called another page (second page) via ajax. In the second page there is a form that send via ajax then reload page once. But when the second page refreshes, my first page refreshes too. But I don't want it. I would like only to reload my inner page. Is there a way to reload only internal page?
Here is my inner page codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.MyForm button[type=submit]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
    var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
    console.log($frm.serialize());
    $.ajax(
        $frm.attr('action'), 
        {
          method: $frm.attr('method'),
          data: $frm.serialize(),
          success: function(data) { $(".error").html(data), window.location.reload();}
   
        }
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.error{width:200px; height:50px;border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form class="MyForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
    <select name="Avg">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="error">Show form success here after page reload</div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Inner page? How are you loading this into your 'parent page'? Iframe? Please clarify

Comment: can you show the whole document(s) as a snippet, possible in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @anu  the page loading with simple onclick event in a div :      $('.div').load('innerpage.htm');

Comment: @stackbaz  the code you posted has an error at  `$(".error").html(data), window.location.reload();`, it should be a `;` instead of a `,` between the statements.

Comment: Then why dont your try the same again. Instead of `window.location.reload();` use `$('.div').html('').load('innerpage.htm');`

Answer (score 4):

`window.location.reload()` will always reload the whole page. Use `load()` function same as you are using it in the first place for loading the inner page

```
 $.ajax(
            $frm.attr('action'), 
            {
              method: $frm.attr('method'),
              data: $frm.serialize(),
              success: function(data) { 
                   $(".error").html(data);
                   $('.div').html('').load('innerpage.htm');// reload the div
              }

            }
        );
```

Comment: what is (.div)?i shoud make that?

Comment: you mentioned it in comments under the question. You mentioned that is how you are loading the inner page. Isnt this the case?

Comment: no that code was for loading second page into main page . my question was how to reload separately the second page . without reload the first page

Comment: Yes that is how you should reload second page into first. `.div` must be a div with class `div` in the first page. If you are confused then post the code how you are loading the second page along with html of first page

Answer (score 0):

Remove method="post" from the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can make internal page in `<iframe>` and then can reload only this section.